# how to get month difference in 2 columns with date value in SQL developer?

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to get the full month difference between `DT_1` and `DT_2`. I tried the `datediff`, `datepart` and `month`, but it didn't work... I use SQL developer, and it shows:

> ORA-00904: "DATEPART": invalid identifier
>   00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

Data :

```
+---------+-----------+---------------+
|   ID    | DT_1      | DT_2          |
+---------+-----------+---------------+
| C111111 | 2018/1/1  | 2018/1/1      | 
| C111112 | 2017/9/30 | 2018/10/25    | 
| C111113 | 2018/10/1 | 2018/10/31    | 
| C111114 | 2018/10/6 | 2018/12/14    | 
+---------+-----------+---------------+
```

Expected results :

- for `C111111`, the month difference should be `0`  (`1-1`)
- for `C111112`, the month difference should be `13` (`22-9`)
- for `C111113`, the month difference should be `0`  (`10-10`)
- for `C111114`, the month difference should be `2`  (`12-10`)

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: Please post the code that generated the error.

Comment: Also, just to make sure - `dt_1` and `dt_2` are `date`s, right?

Answer (score 4):

You may need to see whether DT_1 and DT_2 are date type and then use MONTHS_BETWEEN function to get the date difference in months between two dates. Like Below:

```
SELECT MONTHS_BETWEEN  (TO_DATE('2018/1/1','YYYY/MM/DD'),  TO_DATE('2018/1/1','YYYY/MM/DD') ) "Months"  FROM DUAL;
```

OR,

```
SELECT MONTHS_BETWEEN  (TO_DATE(DT_1,'YYYY/MM/DD'),  TO_DATE(DT_2,'YYYY/MM/DD') ) "Months"  FROM TableName;
```

Comment: I understand the answer but not the upvotes.  `months_between()` doesn't return the results specified by the OP.

Comment: you need to explain more. What do you expect the above query returns and What the OP is asking? Also, show the difference? Upvotes are for varied reasons, that may be beyond a user imagination.

Comment: . . Just run the examples.  As this example shows, neither `trunc()` nor `ceiling()` would produce what the OP wants:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a77c10f563d37a7bf5b499e3804db2b0.

Answer (score 0):

You want to count the number of month boundaries between two values.  That is not what `months_between()` does.  Instead, convert the values to number of months since some point in time and take the difference.

An easy way to do that uses arithmetic:

```
select t.*,
       ( (extract(year from dt_2) * 12 + extract(month from dt_2)) -
         (extract(year from dt_1) * 12 + extract(month from dt_1))
       ) as month_difference
from t;
```

Alternatively, you can use `trunc()` with `months_between()`:

```
select t.*,
       months_between(trunc(dt_2, 'MON'), trunc(dt_1, 'MON'))
```